# Title: CORS error when adding custom headers in fetch GET request from Vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, fetch, request-headers

I am trying to send a GET request from my Vue.js front-end application using the fetch function. The request works fine, but I encounter an error when I try to include a custom header field called 'language'. The error message I receive is:

Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field language is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

here is my code:

```
const result = await fetch('url',
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Custom-Header",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'language': 'en'
    }
  });Ï
```

When I send the same request using Postman, I receive a response successfully. However, when I try it in my front-end application, it returns an error in the browser. It's worth noting that the request works fine without the custom headers.

I would like to know how I can fix this issue. Is it something that I can resolve on my side, or is it a server issue? If it's a server issue, what steps can be taken to address it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: CORS configuration always happens on the server side, where it needs to be addressed. 

Also, postman sends HTTP requests different than browser do and servers can (not always, but in some cases) distinguish between the way they respond to each request.

Comment: Actually, Postman does not care about CORS because there is no JavaScript code whose access to the HTTP reponse should be sandboxed/prevented. Same for Insomnia, Hoppscotch, etc.